# cant trigger click event on pill tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a pill tabs

What I am trying to achieve is to return to  last tab after refresh

```js
function saveTabSelect(e) {
  localStorage.setItem("tagSelected", e.id);
  return true;
}

function retrieveSelected() {
  var curTag = localStorage.getItem("tagSelected");
  var element = document.getElementById(curTag);
  element.classList.add("active");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="pills-1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#pills-1"><i class="icofont icofont-man-in-glasses"></i>1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="pills-2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#pills-2"><i class="icofont icofont-man-in-glasses"></i>2 </a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="pills-3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#pills-3"><i class="icofont icofont-contacts"></i>3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="pills-4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#pills-4"><i class="icofont icofont-contacts"></i>4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="pills-5-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#pills-5"><i class="icofont icofont-contacts"></i>5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="pills-6-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#pills-6"><i class="icofont icofont-contacts"></i>6</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content" id="pills-icontabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-1-tab">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-2-tab">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-3-tab">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-4-tab">Tab 4</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-5-tab">Tab 5</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-6" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-6-tab">Tab 6</div>

</div>
```

every time i click on one of the nav-items i get a console error

Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.tooltip

full error

```html
bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6 Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.tooltip.
set @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
j @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
qe @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
s @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
```

Comment: Can you let us know what the error message is? Might help debug.

Comment: if I understand your question this is the full console error

bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6 Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.tooltip.
set @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
j @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
qe @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
s @ bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6

Comment: Oh the next line in your question is the console error. I thought you were just continuing describing the problem : ) Maybe format the error message in some way? So can't you just search the internet for that error?

Comment: I have made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] even though localStorage does not work in a stacksnippet

Comment: thank you! where can I see the snippet you made?